# Simple perceptron on python

Tags: python, perceptron

I want to create a simple perceptron with three inputs.
$ \sigma(w_1x_1 + w_2x_2 + w_3x_3) $, where $ \sigma = \frac{1}{1 + e^{-x}.} $
$$ L(w) = \sum_i^3(y_i -\sigma(w_1x_1 + w_2x_2 + w_3x_3)); $$

$ \large \frac{dL}{dw} =2(y - \sigma(w_1x_1 + w_2x_2 + w_3x_3))\sigma(1 - \sigma)x.   $

I am trying to program reverse propagate the error. Help, what am I doing wrong.

```
def sigmoid(x):
    return 1/(1 + np.exp(-x))

data_train = np.array([[1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1]])
train_res = np.array([[1], [0], [0], [0]])

weights = 2*np.random.random((3,1)) - 1

for i in range(10000):
    out = sigmoid(np.dot(data_train,weights))
    dE = 2*np.dot(data_train,np.dot((out - train_res),np.dot(out,(1 - out))))
    weights += dE

test = np.array([0, 0, 1])
print(sigmoid(np.dot(test, weights)))
```